# Ionic 2 virtualScroll doesn't draw properly until I scroll

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using a virtualScroll to display a list of cards however I am finding that when I first load the page the cards are all bunched on top of each other near the top of the screen and only space out properly once I scroll:

towers.ts (controller):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TowerPage } from '../tower/tower';
import { Towers } from '../../providers/towers';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-towers',
    templateUrl: 'towers.html'
})
export class TowersPage {

    allTowers: any = [];

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public towers: Towers){ 

        // get all towers 
        this.towers.getAll().then(result => {
            this.allTowers = result;
        });
    }

    viewTower(id){
        this.navCtrl.push(TowerPage, { "id": id});
    }
}
```

towers.ts (provider):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

/*
  Generated class for the Towers provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class Towers {

    towers: any;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
        this.towers = [
            {
                'id' : 1,
                'name' : 'Tower 1',
                'images' : [
                    'http://placehold.it/1500x1000',
                    'http://placehold.it/1200x800',
                    'http://placehold.it/900x500'
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : 2,
                'name' : 'Tower 2',
                'images' : [
                    'http://placehold.it/1500x1000',
                    'http://placehold.it/1200x800',
                    'http://placehold.it/900x500'
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : 3,
                'name' : 'Tower 3',
                'images' : [
                    'http://placehold.it/1500x1000',
                    'http://placehold.it/1200x800',
                    'http://placehold.it/900x500'
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : 4,
                'name' : 'Tower 1',
                'images' : [
                    'http://placehold.it/1500x1000',
                    'http://placehold.it/1200x800',
                    'http://placehold.it/900x500'
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : 5,
                'name' : 'Tower 5',
                'images' : [
                    'http://placehold.it/1500x1000',
                    'http://placehold.it/1200x800',
                    'http://placehold.it/900x500'
                ]
            },
        ];
    }

    getAll(){       
        return Promise.resolve(this.towers);
    }

    getById(id){
        for(var i in this.towers) {
            if(this.towers[i].id == id) {
                return Promise.resolve(this.towers[i]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Towers.html (template):

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Towers</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <ion-content>

        <ion-list [virtualScroll]="allTowers" [approxItemHeight]="'390px'">

          <div *virtualItem="let tower">
              <ion-card>
                    <img src="{{ tower.images[0] }}" (click)="viewTower(tower.id);" />
                    <ion-card-content>
                        <ion-card-title (click)="viewTower(tower.id);">{{tower.name}}</ion-card-title>
                        <p>Lorem ipsu sum dolor amor sit amet</p>
                    </ion-card-content>
                </ion-card>
            </div>

        </ion-list>

    </ion-content>
</ion-content>
```

When the page first loads as mentioned everything is all bunched up like so:

[image: Page Load]

Then as soon as I scroll everything repositions correctly into place:

[image: After scroll]

Also I know I should use ion-img instead of img but I came across an issue with that too so I'm using img  for the time being

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you solve that?

Comment: No not yet I haven't been able to work on it for a while. It may be that it was a bug with the version of Ionic I was using. Next time I revisit it I expect there will be a newer version out so I'll see if updating fixes it at all.